# Trying To set Font Size in JavaScript While Getting Length Value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to set the attributes of the even-title ID to be either 16px or 8px depending on the length of the title. I already added in this code but it doesn't seem like it's taking effect on my website.

```js
var title = document.getElementById("event-title");
var length = title.length;
if(length >= 14){
 title.setAttribute('style','font-size:8px !important;');
}
else {
 title.setAttribute('style','font-size:16px !important;');
}
```

```html
<h2 id="event-title">Example Title Goes Here</h2>
<h2 id="event-title">Example</h2>
```

Any help would be great!

Thanks,

Comment: using the same `id` (unique identifiers) as many times as you can?

Comment: i can add a class to the title elements as well.

Comment: You _cannot_ use the same `id` on multiple HTML elements in the same document.  That is _invalid_ HTML, and will may produce undefined behavior in JavaScript operating on those `ids`.  Use `class` when you have to select multiple elements.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of issues:

1. You have the same `id` value on more than one element.
2. DOM elements don't have a `length` property; you may have wanted `.nodeValue.length` or `.innerHTML.length` or `.innerText.length` or `.textValue.length`. (To figure out which one, refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) to find out what they each are.)

```js
var title = document.getElementById("event-title");
var length = title.innerHTML.length;
if(length >= 14){
 title.setAttribute('style','font-size:8px !important;');
}
else {
 title.setAttribute('style','font-size:16px !important;');
}
```

```html
<h2 id="event-title">Example Title Goes Here</h2>
```

If you're trying to do this with more than one element, you'll want to use something else to identify them (perhaps a class) and you'll need to use a different lookup (perhaps `document.querySelectorAll`). Then you can loop through them to do the above:

```js
var titles = document.querySelectorAll(".event-title");
titles.forEach(function(title) {
  var length = title.innerHTML.length;
  if (length >= 14){
    title.setAttribute('style','font-size:8px !important;');
  }
  else {
    title.setAttribute('style','font-size:16px !important;');
  }
});
```

```html
<h2 class="event-title">Example Title Goes Here</h2>
<h2 class="event-title">Short</h2>
```

(The `NodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll` doesn't have `forEach` on obsolete browsers like IE8-IE11, but you can readily polyfill it:

```
if (typeof NodeList !== "undefined" && NodeList.prototype && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    Object.defineProperty(NodeList.prototype, "forEach", {
        value: Array.prototype.forEach,
        configurable: true
    });
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/cwv1kyjc/). On IE8 or in IE9+ in [in]compatibility mode, you'll also need to polyfill `Array.prototype.forEach`. See MDN for how. Or use a `for` loop.)

---

Side note: If you're using `!important` markers in **inline** styles, it's probably worth stepping back and figuring out why you have things fighting with each other so much, since an inline style wins over a CSS style (regardless of specificity) unless the CSS style has `!important` on it. So you have dualling `!important`s, which suggests some refactoring is in order...

---

Side note 2: Replacing the entire `style` attribute works, but if you want a more fine-grained approach, assign to properties on the element's `style` object: `title.style.fontSize = "8px";`

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the value of the element, which you are not doing. To do so, try:

```
var length = title.textContent.length;
```

And as a note, make sure there are no whitespaces you don't want counted in your title because the .length method will count the whitespace as well. For example:

```
<h2 id="event-title"> Example </h2>
```

Instead of an expected length of 7, this will give you 9.